# Does refresh sandbox overrides the Apex classes, LWC Components and Triggers

Tags: sandbox-refresh, production, full-sandbox

I am thinking to manually refresh the `fullsandbox`  environment to `production` environment. The only doubt is that will it going to override `LWC Components , Apex Classes and Triggers`. Currently, some part of the customization of `fullsandbox` are not yet deployed on production hence I am worried whether I should be refreshing it or not and does it override code related changes ?

Answer (score 2):

Once you activate the refreshed sandbox "The current configuration and data are erased, including application or data changes that you’ve made." which means all the metadata(Including apex, LWC ..etc)  which were in development state are deleted and the metadata present in Production will be in sandbox.

Please find the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_refresh.htm&type=5) for the same

So it is always better to take the backup of the components which were developed and not deployed to production so once the sandbox is refreshed you can deploy the developing elements again.